# Tool to save a larger clipboard

Tags: clipboard

Are there any tools to have a more robust clipboard type feature in windows?

I am using vs.net 2008 (if it has it built-in and I don't know about it?)

I used to have this tool where I created lots of items in my clipboard that I could access using short-cuts, but I forgot that name of that app!

Tips?

Answer (score 2):

I use [ClipX](http://www.bluemars.org/clipx/)

Very stable and low footprint.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/).  It is OpenSource and has grouping and permanent retention.  It also uses a sqllite db so you really have some headroom for screenshots and large text items.

If your looking for just plain outputting text blobs, I use [Quick Macros](http://quickmacros.com) for that and all kinds of other things.

Answer (score 0):

There is one called [ClipCache](http://www.xrayz.co.uk/purchase/get-it-free) which does something similar to what you describe here. At any rate, I recommend it.